# Does console.log() trigger garbage collection?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, console.log

I have written a hybrid game using Cordova for iOS and Android. On some Android devices, the game crashes after a few minutes and a message appears on the screen "(App Name) has stopped". I've been trying to find what crashes it for the past week but I've been unable to find it. I've started a thread about this but today I observed something that warrants its own thread. Please allow me to first tell you something about the crash, and what I've done to try to solve it.

The game uses two canvases. One that's not visible and which isn't part of the DOM (MAINCanvas) and which always has a fixed size regardless of true screen sizes. All drawing is done on that canvas. And another canvas which has the same size as the screen and is visible (DISPLAYCanvas). I store the context for these canvases at the start of the game:

```js
var MAINCanvas = document.createElement( "canvas" );
var DISPLAYCanvas = document.createElement( "canvas" );

document.body.appendChild(DISPLAYCanvas);

MAINCanvas.context = MAINCanvas.getContext("2d", { alpha: false } );
DISPLAYCanvas.context = DISPLAYCanvas.getContext("2d", { alpha: false } );
```

My game's main loop looks like this:

```js
function MainLoop() {
  doStuff();
  doSomeMoreStuff();
  Render(); // This renders all game elements on the invisible MAINCanvas

  DISPLAYCanvas.context.drawImage( MAINCanvas, 0, 0 );

  window.requestAnimationFrame( MainLoop );
}
```

The game crashed every single time after a few minutes of play. To figure out where it crashed, I added a few console.logs:

```js
function MainLoop() {
  console.log( "Stuff" );
  doStuff();
  console.log( "SomeMoreStuff" );
  doSomeMoreStuff();
  console.log( "Render" );
  Render(); // This renders all game elements on the invisible MAINCanvas

  console.log( "Draw" );
  DISPLAYCanvas.context.drawImage( MAINCanvas, 0, 0 );     

  window.requestAnimationFrame( MainLoop );
}
```

As it turned out, it crashed in different places.

I then suspected that maybe this was the culprit:

```js
MAINCanvas.context = MAINCanvas.getContext("2d", { alpha: false } );
DISPLAYCanvas.context = DISPLAYCanvas.getContext("2d", { alpha: false } );
```

I'm adding properties to a DOM object and I remember reading somewhere that's a no-no and it prevents (copies of) the object from being garbage collected. So I changed it in this:

```js
var MAINContext = MAINCanvas.getContext("2d", { alpha: false } );
var DISPLAYContext = DISPLAYCanvas.getContext("2d", { alpha: false };
```

And my mainloop to:

```js
function MainLoop() {
  console.log( "Stuff" );
  doStuff();
  console.log( "SomeMoreStuff" );
  doSomeMoreStuff();
  console.log( "Render" );
  Render(); // This renders all game elements on the invisible MAINCanvas

  console.log( "Draw" );
  DISPLAYContext.drawImage( MAINCanvas, 0, 0 );

  window.requestAnimationFrame( MainLoop );
}
```

And it didn't crash anymore! I was so happy to have finally found what was crashing it after 7 days of pure frustrating debugging. I could play the game without a problem now.

So in order to prepare the game for publishing, I removed the console.log() lines. To be sure, I tested the game again and... it crashed after a few minutes. So I added a single console.log to my mainloop:

```js
function MainLoop() {
  console.log( "Stuff" );
  doStuff();
  doSomeMoreStuff();
  Render(); // This renders all game elements on the invisible MAINCanvas

  DISPLAYContext.drawImage( MAINCanvas, 0, 0 );

  window.requestAnimationFrame( MainLoop );
}
```

Tested it again and it didn't crash. Removed the console.log() and it crashed. I've tried a few times and everytime the console.log() is removed, the game crashes. If I add it, it doesn't. Consistently.

The only thing I can think of now is that console.log somehow triggers garbage collection?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it's the delay that **console.log()** creates in the lifecycle.

Had similar problems in the past.

Try wrapping the code in a **timeout with 0 seconds delay** for threaded running of that loop.

**Example**

```
function MainLoop() {
  //console.log("MainLoop start");
  doStuff();
  doSomeMoreStuff();
  Render(); // This renders all game elements on the invisible MAINCanvas

  DISPLAYContext.drawImage( MAINCanvas, 0, 0 );

  window.setTimeout(function(){
      window.requestAnimationFrame( MainLoop );
  },0);
}
```

Maybe play around with it and add other intensive actions in the same way.

**EDIT:**
You can also try to reduce the framerate - maybe these special Android devices have not enough power to handle the frame rate...

**Example**

```
var framesPerSecond = 10;

function MainLoop() {
  //console.log("MainLoop start");
  doStuff();
  doSomeMoreStuff();
  Render(); // This renders all game elements on the invisible MAINCanvas

  DISPLAYContext.drawImage( MAINCanvas, 0, 0 );

  window.setTimeout(function(){
      window.requestAnimationFrame( MainLoop );
  }, (1000 / framesPerSecond));
}
```

Hope this helps somehow.

**ENJOY!**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. :)

I removed the console.log() and added the setTimeout(), but the game crashed after about a minute of play. Reversed it and it didn't crash. Well... it crashed on me once after playing several games. Also. the Android device I'm testing on is a Qualcomm 810 64bit octacore. It can handle the FPS easily. :)